# Parsec-Parser works alright, but could it be done better?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I try to do this:

Parse a Text in the form:

> Some Text #{0,0,0} some Text #{0,0,0}#{0,0,0} more Text #{0,0,0}

into a list of some data structure:

> [Inside "Some Text ",Outside (0,0,0),Inside " some Text ",Outside (0,0,0),Outside (0,0,0),Inside " more Text ",Outside (0,0,0)]

So these #{a,b,c}-bits should turn into different things as the rest of the text.

I have this code:

```
module ParsecTest where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Monad

type Reference = (Int, Int, Int)

data Transc = Inside String | Outside Reference
              deriving (Show)

text :: Parser Transc
text =  do
         x <- manyTill anyChar ((lookAhead reference) <|> (eof >> return (Inside "")));
         return (Inside x)

transc = reference <|> text

alot :: Parser [Transc]
alot = do
        manyTill transc eof

reference :: Parser Transc
reference = try (do{ char '#';
                  char '{';
                  a <- number;
                char ',';
                b <- number;
                char ',';
                c <- number;
                char '}';
                return (Outside (a,b,c)) })

number :: Parser Int
number = do{ x <- many1 digit;
             return (read x) }
```

This works as expected. You can test this in ghci by typing

> parseTest alot "Some Text #{0,0,0} some Text #{0,0,0}#{0,0,0} more Text #{0,0,0}"

But I think it's not nice.

1) Is the use of `lookAhead` really necessary for my problem?

2) Is the `return (Inside "")` an ugly hack?

3) Is there generally a more concise/smarter way to archieve the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) I think you do need `lookAhead` as you need the result of that parse. It would be nice to avoid running that parser twice by having a `Parser (Transc,Maybe Transc)` to indicate an `Inside` with an optional following `Outside`. If performance is an issue, then this is worth doing.

2) Yes.

3) `Applicative`s

```
number2 :: Parser Int
number2 = read <$> many1 digit

text2 :: Parser Transc
text2 = (Inside .) . (:) 
     <$> anyChar 
     <*> manyTill anyChar (try (lookAhead reference2) *> pure () <|> eof)


reference2 :: Parser Transc
reference2 = ((Outside .) .) . (,,) 
          <$> (string "#{" *> number2 <* char ',') 
          <*> number2 
          <*> (char ',' *> number2 <* char '}')

transc2 = reference2 <|> text2

alot2 = many transc2
```

You may want to rewrite the beginning of `reference2` using a helper like `aux x y z = Outside (x,y,z)`.

EDIT: Changed `text` to deal with inputs that don't end with an `Outside`.

Comment: Thank you. Your version unfortunately produces an error, that initially led to the ugly hack in "text". It will fail even on the string "some". This is what me forced to put the "eof"-check into the  "text"-parser and the empty Inside "" for typing purposes.

Comment: @Sec Oe sorry about that! I had thought that `try` would deal with the `eof` itself.