# Monadic equivalent of applicative <*

Tags: haskell, monads, parsec, applicative

After having read [Anthony's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852484/parsec-parser-works-alright-but-could-it-be-done-better#7853464) on [a style-related parser question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852484/parsec-parser-works-alright-but-could-it-be-done-better), I was trying to convince myself that writing monadic parsers can still be rather compact.

So instead of

```
reference :: Parser Transc
reference = try $ do string "#{"
                     a <- number
                     char ','
                     b <- number
                     char ','
                     c <- number
                     char '}'
                     return $ Outside (a,b,c)
```

We can *simply* have:

```
reference3 :: Parser Transc
reference3 = liftM3 (((Outside .).) .  (,,)) 
             (string "#{" >> number <<! char ',') 
             number
             (char ',' >> number <<! char '}') where 
               (<<!) = liftM2 const
```

Which is very similar to applicative version provided by Anthony:

```
reference2 :: Parser Transc
reference2 = ((Outside .) .) . (,,) 
             <$> (string "#{" *> number2 <* char ',') 
             <*> number2 
             <*> (char ',' *> number2 <* char '}')
```

...except for the `<<!` operator which is conceptually similar to `<*` which is defined as `liftA2 const` meaning "sequence but discard value and use value provided to the left".

Of course << would have been a bad name for `liftM2 const`, it would have suggested that `<<` is equivalent to `flip >>` if we follow the same logic as `>>=` and `=<<`.

I don't find a "liftM2 const" under a single name.  Is this because it is not *that* useful?

Comment: Unrelated, why does your `Outside` constructor take a triple rather than having three arguments?  The latter would make your code nicer.

Comment: @augustss It's not mine. I just took the example from someone else's post. Agreed that curried form would be better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't quite see the problem. Every monad is also an of applicative functor, so you can simply use `(*>)` in the monadic expressions as well.

(At the time of this answer (year 2011), `Applicative` was not a superclass of `Monad`, so it may have been necessary to add a corresponding class instance.)

Comment: Put another way, what would a similar operator whose type restricted it to `Monad` get you? These operators are for statically specifying the flow of a computation, which is exactly what `Applicative`s are for.

Comment: Ok, I think I get the point. The root problem is that Applicative is not a superclass of Monad (unfortunate!). But trying to bring all the Applicative functions and operators to Monad is a silly exercice. It is much more simpler to add an Applicative instance and hence benefit from a more generic abstraction.

Comment: @gawi: Basically, `<<!` would just be a new name for an already existing function (namely `<*`). It's just that the latter function does not actually exist due to some very boring reason (namely that `Applicative` not a superclass of `Monad`).

Comment: @Heinrich Apfelmus But we have `<*>` and `ap`, `pure` and `return`, `*>` and `>>`.  However, `<*` is the only function of `Applicative` not having a monadic equivalent. I can live with that but I was just wondering.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus *For historical reasons, `Applicative` is not a superclass of `Monad` [...]* You may want to update your answer, now that the Functor-Applicative-Monad proposal is in effect.